# Spark Streaming: irregular input rate after Kafka restart

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am currently running a streaming app on spark that consumes a simple kafka topic using the new direct approach (no receivers). Since we had some issues on Kafka cluster, the streaming app experienced some troubles even after all came back to normal on Kafka : some jobs are processing nearly empty rdds and others are processing double sized ones. The arverage input rate is still the same as it used to be but the processing time is not regular as a consequence.

I tried to restart the app but it makes no difference. I did not found any stack or clue on both Kafka and Spark sides.

Could someone tell me how to fix this kind of issue? Or at least where to have a look to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In the direct receiverless approach with Kafka, the Spark Master node reads the current offsets *from each partition of Kafka*, and then tells each worker from which partition to read, and from what offset to what offset. It's stated on the [Spark-Streaming Kafka Integration documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> With `directStream`, Spark Streaming will create as many RDD partitions
>   as there are Kafka partitions to consume, which will all read data
>   from Kafka in parallel. So there is a one-to-one mapping between Kafka
>   and RDD partitions, which is easier to understand and tune.

Let's say you have 3 Spark workers and 3 Kafka partitions (for simplicity). If Kafka doesn't properly partition it's data and partition 1 and 3 end up receiving all the data while partition 2 has no data, you'll end with batches containing 2 partitions which are large, and each spark worker will operate on one of those partitions, which limits the number of parallelism.

This looks like a Kafka issue rather than a Spark issue. I'd suggest looking at how Kafka is partitioning the data for the specific topic you're reading. As a quick workaround, what you can do is repartition the data after reading it from Kafka using [`DStream.repartition`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream).

Comment: Having a closer look to partitions' offsets delta in web UI for several batches, it appears that all partitions are consumed equally. If it is a Kafka issue, it's not linked to rdd partition mapping :(

Comment: @SebastienFalquier Can you show us your Spark DAG? (The transformations you're using on the DStream).

Comment: Unfortunetly, the Spark DAG is not the one to blame since I experience the same problem on 2 apps consuming a distinct topic each one.

Comment: @Sebastien Is it possible to set up a new Kafka cluster to check agains't? Have you tried explicitly repartitioning the data

Comment: When you say repartitioning the data, you mean using `DStream.repartition`?

Comment: @Sebastien Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what was going wrong : kafka cluster topology has changed after the ops, as a result, the broker list used to create direct stream was not up to date. Unfortunetly, spark kafka consumer does not seem to be able to discover and remove brokers automatically...